# AutoCompleteSource stops KeyPress event?

Tags: c#, windows

Simple code C# winform app (visual studio 2010):

A simple form with one text box here is a keyPress event:

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // The keypressed method uses the KeyChar property to check 
            // whether the ENTER key is pressed. 


            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
            {
                Process.Start("http://yahoo.com", null);
            }

        }
```

Works fine if I type in some text in the text box and hit enter, it opens up my default web browser and takes me to a site.

I need to change the text box to autocompletemode = suggestappend and autocompletesource = customsource.  And then I fill it like so:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection s = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            s.Add("Jon ");
            s.Add("2 Jon");
            textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = s;
        }
```

It does the autocomplete as right when I type in a J it comes up with Jon, but now when I hit enter it doesnt fireoff the KeyPress event.  It just sits there.  I tried putting in a break point and when I type in the first letter J it fires the KeyPress event.  Then when i select the string "Jon" from the autocomplete source and then I hit enter the event no longer fires.

Confused :).

Comment: Confirmed the same error in 2K8 in a simple example.  Seems pretty weird, I tried changing the settings for AcceptsReturn, CausesValidation, etc.... No dice.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem the Return key press is being handled because of the auto-complete suggestion drop-down list - you could always use the **KeyDown** event which still fires in this scenario.

Comment: Agreed, this should be handled at KeyDown.